# call variables in hyberlinks in do loop for bash script

Tags: loops

I am coding a bash script to download some NETCD4 data from a certain web link using wget.

I write a do loop in the script:

```
for((i=1980;i<=1982;i++))
do
'${i}.nc4' 'http://usr.${i}.nc4' '' ''
done
```

to download those data like this
http://usr.1980.nc4
etc

but i found that the script cannot recognize the stuff as hyberlink after the dollar sign (i.e. http://usr. is a link; the other part is not)

How to solve this ?

Thanks a lot